# Parse : Retrieving properties from an object that is related

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

So I am doing a query to bring back a list of records, these records have a link to the user that created the record.  The link is to the object.

My query gets me the object but I cant then access the fields of that object (except of course ID)

```
query.equalTo("search", search);
        query.include("user");
        query.find({
            success: function(Report) {
                for (var i = 0; i < Report.length; i++) {
                    var test = Report[i].id;
                    query.get(test, {
                        success: function(result) {
                            var reportDescription = result.get("reportDescription");
                            var reportPicture = result.get("reportPicture");
                            var reportPosition = result.get("reportPosition");
                            var reportType = result.get("reportType");
                            var reportDate = result.get("createdAt").toLocaleString();
                            var reportSearchId = result.get("search").id;

                            var user = result.get("user")
                            console.log(user)
                            var reportSearchBy =  user.username;

                        },
                        error: function(result, error) {
                            alert(error.message);
                        }
                    });
                };
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }
        });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i tried to run similar code to what you did. when i tried to access with dot notation i get undefined but when i tried to get it with .get("fieldName") it works..

here is my code:

```
  var FileTest = Parse.Object.extend("FileTest");
  var query = new Parse.Query(FileTest);
  query.include("user");
  query.find().then(function(results){

    var lastItem = results[results.length - 1];
    if (lastItem){
      var user = lastItem.get("user");
      console.log(user.get("username"));
    }

  },function(error){

  });
```

please notice that i also use Promise for better coding and in order to get the username i did **lastItem.get("username")**
so please try to replace **user.username** with **user.get("username")**
and see if it works.

Comment: You rock dude! Thank you!